# Current feedback amplifier input structure

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, conversion, transimpedance

This is an input stage of some obsolete CFA (current feedback amplifier):

[image]

Current feedback amplifier is a transimpedance amplifier, which converts current signal at its input into voltage signal at its output. R_in of non-inverting pin is high resistance input, while other R_in of inverting pin is low resistance input.
In general, if R_in goes to infinity, then the input only sees the voltage at its input nodes and if R_in goes to zero, then the input only sees the current at its input nodes, right? However, in case of this CFA, -Vin sees current signal rather than voltage (due to lower input resistance) and +Vin sees voltage signal rather than current (due to higher input resistance), right? ***On what fact should one decide, whether this amplifier is transimpedance amplifier?*** I would say that when it operates as inverting amplifier, it is transimpedance amplifier (I to V conversion) and when it operates as non-inverting amplifier, it is voltage amplifier (V to V conversion). But I may be wrong.

It is easier to determine the type of amplifier in case of differential input structure, where both inputs are high impedance inputs (case of VFA - voltage feedback amplifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, a CFA can be - and is - used as a voltage amlifier. But the feedback path is always connected to the low-resistive inverting input and, hence, the signal which is coupled back is always a CURRENT. This explains the name: Current-Feedback Amplifier. But this does not mean that the amplifier could be used for transimpedance applications only.

More than that, the node in your drawing labelled as Vout is NOT a low-resistive voltage output. Instead, it is a high impedance node (current output) which produces a voltage across an internal transimpedance - and this voltage is transferred to a buffer providing the low-resistive voltage output.

Comment: Okay. But without buffer stage (not shown here), this circuit is a current amplifier (assume feedback to inverting input)? Current in - current out?

Comment: There is one type of CFA (AD844) which allows access to the high-impedance node (without using the buffer mode). And in this mode, the CFA works as a "current conveyor": Non-inv. high-resistive voltage input, inverting low-resistive current input and high-resistive current output. A very versatile unit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. 
Are you talking about CFA topology by itself or you want to analyze the CFA used in a specific circuit configuration?

Notice that in classic VFA amplifier when we are using it as inverting amplifier. We have a "virtual short", so we can treat the op-amp and RF resistor as a transimpedance amplifier and R1 resistor as a voltage to current converter.

Also, do you consider this circuit as a CFA amplifier also?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK2RUH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because this circuit also will have a low input resistance at inverting input.

And when we are looking at the circuit from a classical defined a feedback theory point of view. The topology of this circuit is a voltage-series feedback amplifier (series-shunt).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL2S0p.png)</sup>

The only difference is the complementary circuit working in AB class. 
And I suspect that your circuit is called a CFA because of the fact that the "error" current at the input stage is mirrored and further processed by the circuit.

Comment: What kind of circuit is the lower circuit you shown? Voltage seen at input (so voltage-in) due to higher resistance, then output taken at input complementary pair's emitter, which is seen as voltage source. Then you have a voltage amplification stage. Output taken at collector, which means the output signal is current, right? Then this is again converted to voltage using buffer.

Comment: @Keno This is a CFA amplifier working in the non-inverting configuration.